# ImportError for pysmt-install --msat with pySMT on Python 3.11

Tags: windows, python-3.11, pysmt

I have Python 3.11 on Windows 11 and have pySMT 0.9.5 installed.  However, I cannot get an SMT solver installed, e.g. MathSAT.  I have done this in the past on some older Python and it worked well, so in principle this seems to work.

When I run `pysmt-sinatll --msat` I get this:

```
    C:\Users\chris\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py:66: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated.
    !!

            ********************************************************************************
            Please avoid running ``setup.py`` directly.
            Instead, use pypa/build, pypa/installer or other
            standards-based tools.

            See https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2021/10/setup-py-deprecated.html for details.
            ********************************************************************************

    !!
    self.initialize_options()
```

Apart from that, the compile seems to run well and I even get the files that are presumably needed in the directory `C:\Users\chris\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages`.

```
    03.10.2023  12:14         4.895.744 mathsat.dll
    03.10.2023  12:14            75.000 mathsat.py
    03.10.2023  12:14           429.056 mpir.dll
    03.10.2023  12:15    <DIR>          yices_bin
    03.10.2023  12:14           517.632 _mathsat.cp311-win_amd64.pyd
    03.10.2023  12:14    <DIR>          __pycache__
```

However, when I try to load it, I get:

```
    >>> import mathsat
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\mathsat.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "c:\users\chris\anaconda3\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 676, in _load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 573, in module_from_spec
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1233, in create_module
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
    ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _mathsat: The specified module could not be found.

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\mathsat.py", line 21, in <module>
    _mathsat = swig_import_helper()
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\mathsat.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_mathsat')
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "c:\users\chris\anaconda3\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _mathsat: The specified module could not be found.
```

Can anybody help me?